# Unable to locate a button

Tags: python, selenium, web

i want to click on a cookie button but i cant, i try to see if there is any iframe but there is not. Tank you for anyone who help me! Here is the site : https://serveur-prive.net/minecraft/hiveria-13093/vote
my code :

```
import random
import string
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from colorama import Fore

# driver_options
def main():
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")

    chrome_options.add_extension("NopeCHA-CAPTCHA-Solver.crx")
    chrome_options.add_extension("C:/Users/Alban/PycharmProjects/Programming/NopeCHA-CAPTCHA-Solver.crx")
    chrome_options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
    print(Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "################### " + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX
          + "Auto Vote Hiveria" + Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + " ###################")
    print(Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + "                      Version 1.0")
    print()
    pseudo = input("Pseudonyme Minecraft : ")

    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, version_main=108)

    driver.get('https://www.hiveria.fr/vote')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(8)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="stepNameInput"]').send_keys(pseudo)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="voteNameForm"]/button').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    # vote 1
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="vote-card"]/div[3]/div[1]/a').click()
    time.sleep(13811)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]'))).click()
    time.sleep(8.5)

    # vote 2
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="vote-card"]/div[3]/div[2]/a').click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    #time.sleep(8.5)
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/input[2]').send_keys(pseudo)
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/button').click()
    #driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])


    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    # vote 3
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="vote-card"]/div[3]/div[3]/a').click()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pseudo"]').send_keys(pseudo)
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="vote-button-action"]').click()

    time.sleep(1000)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # freeze_support() here if program needs to be frozen
    main()
```

screenshot:

[image]

screenshot before entering the site, button text is 'serveur-prive.net':

[image]

Comment: It's unclear. You open `https://www.hiveria.fr/vote` then insert text and click there, OK. But where and how you open this page `https://serveur-prive.net/minecraft/hiveria-13093/vote`?

Comment: the link "https://serveur-prive.net/minecraft/hiveria-13093/vote" is when you insert the name and click OK, it's the first button with the text 'serveur-prive.net' i modified my question to show you where is it.

Comment: Can you share ALL your Selenium code as it?

Comment: yes i can i post it right now, in pseudonyme minecraft you can put any minecraft username like 'CallMeSeez' or 'Fan2Poney'.

Comment: I tried now but can't access the page due to cloudflare blocking...

Comment: mmhhhh weird bcs personally i can pass with undetected chromedriver try just to go on ' https://serveur-prive.net/minecraft/hiveria-13093/vote' directly because my probleme is not on the hiveria site. I just want to click a button cookie.

Comment: I opened the link you pasted here, but I see nothing there matching this XPath `//*[@id="vote-card"]/div[3]/div[1]/a`, even not this `//*[@id="vote-card"]`. So I don't understand what do you mean, I'm sorry